# How do I create a formula in excel that compares text in cells and returns a percentage

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, percentage

I have a excel spreadsheet that every cell will have either three values, Pass, Fail or na(not available). [This is an example of what the spreadsheet will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TozB.png)

So I will like to have a formula that will compare all the cells and returned 100% "completion" when all the cells have "Pass" on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Pass")/COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"<>na")
```

Then format the output cell as Percentage.

This will return the percentage of cells that have "Pass" in them out of all the cells that are not `na` in A1:A10<sup>(1)</sup>.

[image]

---

<sup>(1)</sup>
As your picture does not include row and column references, I put a general range in my formula, you will want to change the range reference to those of the range to be tested.

Comment: Excellent! It worked! I change to the correct cell ranges, now, what if I want to ignore all the "na's" in that range. Meaning in your example it would be 9 cells being counted in which 7 have pass, so that should be 77.77%, I know I could just select manually all the cells that don't have "Pass on them" but my spreadsheet will have "na's" all over the place.

Comment: Do you want to ignore all the `na`s and blanks?

Comment: see edit @AndresMartinez  remember that if this answer your question, mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: thanks but there is one more issue that I have. In a row
Intentional Emissions  fail na pass
I have the formula given by you: =COUNTIF(D43:F43,"Pass")/COUNTIFS(D43:F43,"<>na")
and if I put Pass, marks 33% (which is good), if I type "Fail" stays at 33%(still good), but if I type "na" it goes to 50%.

Comment: You said to not include `na` in the output.  D43:F43 only has 3 cells, so if one is `na` you now only are looking at two so if one is "Pass" it is 50%.  That is what you explained you wanted in the first comment.

Comment: Ok, got it, Thank you again for your help!